# Angularjs $setPristine not working with controller as syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

$setPristine works alright when referenced with $scope but doesn't seem to work with 'controller as syntax'

**In View:**

```
<h2>With Controller as syntax</h2>
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first">
    <form name="form1" id="form" novalidate>
        <input name="name" ng-model="first.data.name" placeholder="Name" required/>
        <button class="button" ng-click="first.reset()">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <p>Pristine: {{form1.$pristine}}</p>
    <p> <pre>Errors: {{form.$error | json}}</pre> </p>
</div>
<hr>

<h2>With $scope</h2>
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <form name="form1" id="form" novalidate>
        <input name="name" ng-model="data.name" placeholder="Name" required/>
        <button class="button" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <p>Pristine: {{form1.$pristine}}</p>
    <p> <pre>Errors: {{form.$error | json}}</pre> </p>
</div>
```

**In app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = { "name": ""};

    vm.reset = function() {
      vm.data.name = "";
      vm.form1.$setPristine();
    }
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope) {
  'use strict';
  $scope.data = { "name": ""};

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.data.name = "";
      $scope.form1.$setPristine();
    }
});
```

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VcgZx3?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you use `controller as` syntax, the form and other attributes are still bound to the scope not to the controller instance so you still have to use `$scope.form1.$setPristine();` to set the form's state.

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
  'use strict';
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = {
    "name": ""
  };

  vm.reset = function() {
    vm.data.name = "";
    $scope.form1.$setPristine();
  }
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope) {
  'use strict';
  $scope.data = {
    "name": ""
  };

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.data.name = "";
    $scope.form1.$setPristine();
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="my-app">
  <h2>With Controller as syntax</h2>
  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first">
    <form name="form1" id="form" novalidate>
      <input name="name" ng-model="first.data.name" placeholder="Name" required/>
      <button class="button" ng-click="first.reset()">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <p>Pristine: {{form1.$pristine}}</p>
    <p> <pre>Errors: {{form.$error | json}}</pre> </p>
</div>
<hr/>

<h2>With $scope</h2>
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
  <form name="form1" id="form" novalidate>
    <input name="name" ng-model="data.name" placeholder="Name" required/>
    <button class="button" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
  </form>
  <p>Pristine: {{form1.$pristine}}</p>
  <p> <pre>Errors: {{form.$error | json}}</pre> </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the other attributes that are still bound to the scope and not to the controller instance?

Comment: @shyamalparikh only attributes that you are binding to `first` in the template or added to `this` or vm in the controller

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using Arun's suggestion of accessing the form through `$scope` is simply to ensure the form is accessible through the controller.

To do this all you have to do is change your HTML for the 'controller as' version very slightly. Change the form's name to include the controller object, also change any references to the form from the template to include the controller variable:

```
   <h2>With Controller as syntax</h2>
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first">
    <form name="first.form1" id="form" novalidate>
        <input name="name" ng-model="first.data.name" placeholder="Name" required/>
        <button class="button" ng-click="first.reset()">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <p>Pristine: {{first.form1.$pristine}}</p>
    <p> <pre>Errors: {{form.$error | json}}</pre> </p>
</div>
<hr>
```

Your Javascript will now run unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

I think an even easier way to accomplish this is to provide the form controller as a parameter to the `reset()` function:

```
…
<button class="button" ng-click="reset(form1)">Reset</button>
…
```

and change the `reset()` function slightly, so that it uses the supplied parameter:

```
$scope.reset = function(form) {
  $scope.data.name = "";
  form.$setPristine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $setPristine  without $scope:

```
  <form ng-submit="$ctrl.save()" name="$ctrl.myForm">
```

And in your controller:

```
var $ctrl = this;
 ...   
$ctrl.myForm.$setPristine();
$ctrl.myForm.$setUntouched();
```

It works for me. (*AngularJS v1.5.7*)